# How to loop through JSON array in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, node-request

I'm trying to read value from json array to display in the page. I have tried with below code but couldn't make it. I was trying long time to get this done and Please advise what am I doing wrong here.

Also I'm not able to do JSON.parse- unexpected input error.

```
http.request(options, function(res) {
res.on('data', function (result) {
console.log(result);//Displaying below format of result without any error
console.log(result.Reference[0].name); Error //TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.
console.log(result.Reference.length);//Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

JSON format: when printing result

```
{
        "Reference": [
            {
                "name": "xxxxxxxx",
                "typeReference": {
                 "articulation": 0,
                "locked": false,
                "createdBy": {
                     "userName": "System",
                              },
                "lastModifiedBy": {
                                  "userName": "System",
                                 },

                "lastModified": 1391084398660,
                "createdOn": 1391084398647,
                "isSystem": true
            },
            "communityReference": {
                "name": "xxxxxx",
                "language": "English",
                "sbvr": false,
                 "parentReference": {
                    "name": "xxxxx",
                    "sbvr": false,
                    "meta": false,
                    "parentReference": null,
                    "locked": false,
                    "createdBy": {
                        "userName": "xxxxx",
                           },
                    "lastModifiedBy": {
                        "userName": "xxxxx",
                           },

                    "lastModified": 1459185726230,
                    "createdOn": 1456337723119,
                    "isSystem": false
                },
                "locked": false,
                "createdBy": {
                     "userName": "xxxxx",
                           },
                "lastModifiedBy": {
                    "userName": "xxxxxx",
                          },

                "lastModified": 1472655031590,
                "createdOn": 1472654988012,
                "isSystem": false
            },
            "locked": false,
            "createdBy": {
                  "userName": "xxxxx",

            },
            "lastModifiedBy": {

                "userName": "xxxxx",
                "firstName": "xxxxx",

            },

            "lastModified": 1473171981520,
            "createdOn": 1472655253366,
            "isSystem": false
        },
        {
        "name":"yyyyyy", same attribute type as above.
          ...
        },
        {
        ..
        },
```

Comment: Did you check that your `result` is not a string?

Comment: If you're getting an unexpected input error when you do `JSON.parse(result)` then it may not be valid JSON.

Comment: If result is a string, you first need to convert it to an object `var obj = JSON.parse(result);
obj.Reference[0];
`

Comment: i have verified that result is string using typeof(result).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`res` is a stream, and the [data](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data) event indicates that it has received some data, but it may or may not be all the data. You're not likely to get all the data at once, so you need to wait until the [end](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end) event fires, when you have the whole JSON object:

```
var json = '';
res.on('data', function ( chunk ) {
  json += chunk;
} );
res.on('end', function ( ) {
  var result = JSON.parse( json );
  console.log( result.Reference[0].name );
} );
```

or you can use [json-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-stream) which can read in JSON chunk by chunk and handle that correctly, unlike JSON.parse.

However, I recommend that you don't use either of the above solutions and instead use [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request), which greatly simplifies this and other aspects of making HTTP requests and handling the response.

Comment: I have changed method to request and now working good. Just remove the code and will accept the answer.

Comment: Hi @user2848031 , I'm glad my suggestion helped you! I'm not going to remove the code from my answer because I see it as part of the explanation for what was causing the problem in the first place, and I think that is an essential part of the answer. If you rather accept an answer that mentions only the `request` module you can add that answer and self-accept it, otherwise if you feel like my answer fully solved your problem I appreciate you accepting it in its current state.

Comment: I don't support this answer without basic validation, error checking and directly attempting to read members off objects.

Comment: @VeereshDevireddy: That's kind of silly. For all its verbosity, your answer  ultimately only changes the console message from an Error to a log. Either way, a message is printed and the desired code won't be able to continue.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this with some additional and safe validations:

```
{
  if ( result ) {
    var data = (typeof result == "string") ? JSON.parse(result) : result;
    if (data.hasOwnProperty("Reference")) {
      for(var i = 0; i < data.Reference.length; i++; ) {
        try {
            var reference = data.Reference[i];
            console.log("Name:" + reference.name);
            //Your app logic
        } catch(e) {
            //In case if any invalid references, then continue with others
            console.warn("Error processing reference - " + e);
        }
      }
    } else {
      console.warn("No References were found!");
    }
  } else {
    console.error("Invalid JSON!");
  }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: One shouldn't down vote other answer without comments just to support theirs.  This one works far better with basic validations and have safe execution than other answers.

Comment: I hadn't downvoted, but after that comment making it sound like I did, and along with the fact that your answer uses `JSON.parse` which the OP said isn't working for them, I decided to.